# groovy + spring integration jpa: linkage error

Tags: jpa, groovy, spring-integration

Using Spring integration JPA + Groovy

I got the following error:

Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.JpaExecutor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/persistence/LockModeType"

Here are my dependencies :

dependencies {

```
compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jpa:3.0.4.RELEASE'
compile 'org.apache.openjpa:openjpa:2.3.0'
compile group: 'hsqldb', name: 'hsqldb', version: '1.8.0.10'    
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6'
```

}

Here is my spring context :

```
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter
                channel="jpaInboundChannel"
                entity-manager="entityManagerFactory"
                jpa-query="select p from Person p"
                auto-startup="true" >
    <int:poller fixed-rate="2000">
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"          ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"    ref="vendorAdaptor" />
    <property name="packagesToScan"      value="com.univ"/>     
</bean>

<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" />

<bean id="vendorAdaptor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter"
    parent="abstractVendorAdaptor">
</bean> 

<bean id="abstractVendorAdaptor" abstract="true">
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="database"    value="HSQL" />
    <property name="showSql"     value="false"/>
</bean>

<int:service-activator input-channel="jpaInboundChannel" ref="service" method="method"></int:service-activator>

<bean id="service" class="com.univ.Service" />
```

The Groovy main programs contains :

ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/applicationContext.xml")

What can I do ? Thank you.

Comment: There is any Groovy in that sample. I'm not sure how to help you if we don't have any hook to test/debug. Sorry, it looks like a bad question...

Comment: This is probably a build-setup issue... where you have two dependencies, both of which bring in different versions of LockModeType class.  If you're using Maven, check your dependency map and look for jars known to contain LockModeType.

Comment: @billjamesdev, that definitely makes sense. I really see the `LockModeType` in the `org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence` and `org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`. @B. Charroux ?